# Reconstruction Conjecture and Partial 2-trees

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, treewidth

[Reconstruction conjecture](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/reconstruction_conjecture) says that graphs (with at least three vertices) are determined uniquely by their vertex deleted subgraphs. This conjecture is five decades old.

Searching relevant literature, I found that the following classes of graphs are known to be reconstructible :

- trees
- disconnected graphs, graphs whose complement is disconnected
- regular graphs
- Maximal Outerplanar Graphs
- maximal planar graphs
- outerplanar graphs
- Critical blocks
- Separable graphs without end vertices
- unicyclic graphs (graphs with one cycle)
- non-trivial cartesian product graphs
- squares of trees
- bidegreed graphs
- unit interval graphs
- threshold graphs
- nearly acyclic graphs (i.e., G-v is acyclic)
- cacti graphs
- graphs for which one of the vertex deleted graph is a forest.

I recently proved that a *special case* of partial 2-trees are reconstructible. I am wondering if partial 2-trees (a.k.a [series-parallel graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph)) are known to be reconstructible. Partial 2-trees do not seem to fall into any of the above mentioned categories.

- Am I missing any other known classes of reconstructible graphs in the above list ?
- In particular, are partial 2-trees known to be reconstructible ?

Comment: I don't have access to it, but this paper: http://www.springerlink.com/content/p6r03877310411wr/ claims that N-free ordered sets are reconstructible.

Comment: To further elaborate on @mhum's comment: series-parallel partial orders are precisely those that are N-free, so the paper is claiming that series-parallel posets are reconstructible.  The transitive reductions of series-parallel posets are the series-parallel graphs, but I'm not sure how the reconstruction conjecture interacts with the transitive edges.

Comment: For your list: Kiyomi, Saitoh, and Uehara showed that [Bipartite Permutation Graphs Are Reconstructible](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-17461-2_29).

Comment: One more for your list: [some planar graphs are reconstructible](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1279202).

Comment: Shiva, Did you get any new result?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that it has not been shown that bidegreed graphs are reconstructible. Bidegreed graphs are edge-reconstructible. Kocay did some work on reconstruction of bidegreed graphs, but did not reach a comprehensive result that I have been able to find. The notion that it has been proven that bidegreed graphs are reconstructible seems to be a bit of misinformation circulating on the web.